# How to prove that Linear-Fractional Transformations map circles/straight lines onto circles/straight lines?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

There this theorem that states the Linear Fractional Transformations map circles and straight lines to circles and straight lines. How can you prove this?

This is what the theorem states in my lecture notes: "Every Linear Fractional Transformation maps circles and straight lines in the $z$-plane on circles and straight lines in the $w$-plane (but not necessarily circles onto circles and straight lines onto straight lines)."

I've tried showing the $w=1/z$ does it by writing the equation of a circle with $z$ then with $z=1/w$ and showed that we have circles in both cases. Then you can argue that the Linear Fractional Mapping formula is a combination of rotations and translations of $w=1/z$.

However this does not seem to be enough. Any thoughts ?

Many thanks !

Comment: "There this theorem that states..." What theorem? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: @KBS I don't know the name of the theorem, just what it states. I saw in in various notes and books but they never gave a name.

Comment: Then, provide a link to that theorem or state it completely in your question.

Comment: @KBS I've stated it completely in my questions. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Seems like this link answers your questions: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Complex_Variables_with_Applications_(Orloff)/11%3A_Conformal_Transformations/11.07%3A_Fractional_Linear_Transformations

Comment: Yes I did see that but I wanted to know if there was other proofs.

Comment: I think your idea is fine. The transformation $(az+b)/(cz+d)$ with $ad-bc\neq 0$ is a composition of transformations of the form $w=1/z$ and of the form $w=az+b.$ There is no problem with the second one. The first one takes circles not containing $0$ to circles, and circles containing $0$ to lines.